# Installation of Pygame in windows 7 64bit with Anaconda 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, anaconda

I used anaconda 4.4.0 with python 3.6 version also used windows 7, 64 bit. I want to install pygame in anaconda. I tried in many ways but i got a error like this
[Error Form anaconda prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Urr5.png)

It said

> Unsatisfiable Error: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>   -pygame-->> python 2.7*
>   ->>python 3.6*

Noted that I have used "`conda install -c prkrekel pygame`" for pygame installation. But every time got that error. What's the way to solve the error?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/03/installing-the-windows-64-bit-version-of-pygame/) help?
Seems like your system has two versions of Python installed, and Anaconda is not "getting" the PyGame install.

Can you try

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame
```

OR

```
conda install -c tlatorre pygame=1.9.2
```

OR

In the Anaconda menu, choose Tools, then "open command prompt".
The cmd window will open inside Anaconda. Now type

```
pip install pygame
```

Comment: nope, i just installed anaconda 4.4 and now am trying to install pygame by anaconda prompt but it creates this error. there is no another version python in my laptop.

Comment: Can you try
    conda install -c cogsci pygame
OR
    conda install -c tlatorre pygame=1.9.2
OR

In the Anaconda menu, choose Tools, then "open command prompt".
The cmd window will open inside Anaconda. Now type 
"pip install pygame".

Comment: yes, last one has worked. Thank you so much. I spend whole day for install it. Finally i get a solution. Many many thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked for you Nayan :)
I once spent five hours hunting for a missing '\n' :D

Comment: i feel relax now. I spend almost 7 hour time and may be install and uninstall 30 times with 32 bit, 64 bit anaconda, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have pygame installed which is for an older version python 2.7. You just have to uninstall the package and install the latest one that supports python 3.6.